# What is the distance between a hyperbola's vertex and center?

Tags: geometry, terminology, analytic-geometry, conic-sections

What is the name for the distance between a hyperbola's center and vertex? Is this the semimajor axis?  And, given an equation of a hyperbola, how can this distance be found?

Comment: Using "(semi-)major axis" and "(semi-)minor axis" in the context of a hyperbola is problematic, as the terms connote that the former is *longer* than the latter, which isn't necessarily so (in contrast to the ellipse case). The traditional alternatives are "(semi-)transverse axis" (connecting the branches) and "(semi-)conjugate axis" (the other one), but it can be annoying to have to switch terms when, say, discussing a *family* of conics that include ellipses and hyperbolas. I sometimes use "(semi-)focal (or primary) axis" and "(semi-)secondary axis" for generality.

Comment: @Blue Is the major axis longer than the minor axis for all non-degenerate hyperbolas? Or is it not necessary either?

Comment: @Aurelius: *"Is the major axis longer than the minor axis ... ?"* Part of the problem with calling a hyperbola's axes "major" and "minor" is that the terms *suggest* that the first is longer than the second; this is true for ellipses, but not hyperbolas. For a hyperbola, the axis through the foci could be longer than, shorter than, or equal to the other axis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbola) and [Mathworld](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperbola.html) define the semi-major axis of a hyperbola exactly as you do; equivalently it's half the distance between the two branches.

This is useful for analogies to the ellipse; origin-centred Cartesian equations for the curves are
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
for the ellipse and
$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}-\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$$
for the hyperbola, where $a$ and $b$ are the semi-axes.

It's possible to calculate the semi-major axis for a hyperbola in general position too (but a bit messy) - is that of interest?